# ERROR 211: La variable (NUMS(1)) no esta definida(pseint)

Tags: pseint

```
Algoritmo sin_titulo
    Dimension nums[3];
    
    nums[1]<-100;
        
    Escribir nums[1];
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

No entiendo como definir un array

Comment: Ni idea tengo de qué es pseint ni de su utilidad, pero según [esto](https://www.discoduroderoer.es/arreglos-o-arrays-en-pseudocodigo/) te faltan varias cosas

Answer (score 0):

Falta definir el arreglo `nums`.
Los arreglos de definen como cualquier variable (ver ayuda de PSeInt y el manual presente en internet).

Recordar que en PSeInt establecer un arreglo o dimension no implica nunca establecer su tipo de dato.

Tu programa quedaría así

```
Algoritmo sin_titulo
    Dimension nums[3];
    Definir nums Como Entero;
    
    nums[1]<-100;
        
    Escribir nums[1];
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer algo como esto para definir un Array, la declaración de un array generalmente se hace al principio del programa o función.

```
Algoritmo Ejemplo
    Dimension nums[3]; // Dimensionado del arreglo a 3 elementos
    Definir nums Como Entero;  // Declaración del array
    
    nums[1] <- 100;  // Asignación de valor al segundo elemento
    
    Escribir "Valor en nums[1]: ", nums[1];  // Mostrar el valor asignado
    
    Leer nums[1];  // Leer un nuevo valor para el segundo elemento
    
    Escribir "Nuevo valor en nums[1]: ", nums[1];  // Mostrar el nuevo valor asignado
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!